# sql server skip error on inserting multiple rows at a time

Tags: sql-server

I am doing a batch process. In my process I build a set of insert query statements and will run from my application. I won't use sql transactions and want to skip the statement which throws error.

For example:

```
create table test
(
test varchar(20)
)

insert into test (test) values ('test1'); -- 1 row affected
insert into test (test) values ('test2'); -- 1 row affected
insert into test (test) values ('a' + 333); -- This will throw error while executing and i ---want to skip this
insert into test (test) values ('test4'); -- This should be affected as per my requirement
```

Is it possible such type of process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping each insert statement in [try catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could just surround each INSERT statement with a try-catch block, e.g.

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO test...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     --Do nothing
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this you can't, unless you do one of

- submit row by row
- wrap each INSERT in a TRY/CATCH

bcp and BULK INSERT have a [MAXERRORS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) option which isn't exposed in the .net [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class, which may be better way to do it...